# If statement completely ignored

Tags: php, codeigniter

Alright so I have this Codeigniter code where I use the Cart Library. Now, my problem is my if doesn't seem to work in that particular function in the Controller. I wanted to check if the user's current credits are bigger than the price of the thing, it will add the item to the cart, and if it's lesser then it would redirect to the login page (as a test only). but somehow it just won't acknowledge the presence of that If statement and completely ignores it. Any ideas?

**Controller**

```
 function go_addtocart_user($user)
  {

    $id=$this->input->post('id_things');
    $price=$this->input->post('price_things');
    $name=$this->input->post('name_things');
    $getalluser=$this->user->get_credit_user($user);

foreach ($getalluser as $row){

 if($row>=$price)
  {
  $this->user->decrease_things_stock($name);
  $this->user->decrease_credit($user,$price);
  $this->user->insert_to_cart($id,$price,$name);
  }
else{
  redirect("main/go_login/");
    }
 }
 redirect("main/go_home/".$user);
}
```

**Model**

```
   public function get_credit_user($name){
    $this->db->select('credit');
    $this->db->from('user');
    $this->db->where('username', $name);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result=$query->result_array();
    return $result;
  }
  public function decrease_credit($username,$price){
   $this->db->where('username', $username);
   $this->db->set('credit', 'credit - ' . (int) $price, FALSE);
   $this->db->update('user');
   return true;
 }
  public function decrease_things_stock($name){
   $this->db->where('name', $name);
   $this->db->set('stock', 'stock-1', FALSE);
   $this->db->update('things');
   return true;
 }
  public function insert_to_cart($id,$price,$name){
   $data = array(
   'id' => $id,
   'name' => $name,
   'qty' => 1,
   'price' => $price
   );
   $this->cart->insert($data);
}
```

Comment: What is the value and type of `$row`? Seems to me that would be an array or an object and wouldn't make a logical comparison to `$price`.

Comment: What I see is, regardless of whatever that if/else statement does, you are asking for another redirection at the end of each loop: `redirect("main/go_home/".$user);` So this won't satisfy your need for login page redirection.

Comment: As `get_credit_user()` returns an array -> `$result=$query->result_array(); return $result;`, you need to get the `credit` value -> `if($row['credit']>=$price)`

Comment: @Sean well I'll be damned, that actually worked. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you are only selecting 1 column value in your query -

```
$this->db->select('credit');
```

The function `result_array()` returns an array, not a single value, ie.

```
$result=$query->result_array(); 
return $result;
```

returns

```
$result => array('credit'=>[value])
```

So you need to specify the column in either your `if()` -

```
if($row['credit']>=$price)
```

**or** in your function return -

```
$result=$query->result_array(); 
return $result['credit'];
```